# Did I translate the very short C code correctly into assembler?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm currently learning assembly x86 and I have made a little task for myself.

The C code:

```
if (a == 4711) { a = a + 2 } else
               { a = a - 2 }
```

Assembler Code (`eax` is a register, `cmp` is compare, `jne` is jump if not equal and `jmp` is jump if equal):

```
         mov eax, a
         cmp eax, 4711
         jmp equal
equal:   add eax, 2
         jne unequal
unequal: sub eax, 2
```

I think a little more efficient than that would be:

```
         mov eax, a
         cmp eax, 4711
         jne unequal
         add eax, 2
unequal: sub eax, 2
```

Edit:

```
         mov eax, a
         cmp eax, 4711
         jne unequal
equal:   add eax, 2
         jmp continue
unequal: sub eax, 2
continue: ...
```

Did I translate it correctly?

Comment: no, you didn't. you add 2 if they're unequal, but then you UNCONDITIONALLY subtract 2 again.

Comment: Wow I'm trying to learn and get an instant minus point. This didn't even happen ONCE in the maths section, just saying.

Comment: downvotes are a fact of life here. I didn't downvote, but your question is TRIVIALLY testable by yourself, if you'd even bothered to try. We're happy to help with actual problems. we're not here to enable you to be lazy.

Comment: your last edit seems to be correct now.

Comment: Hmm my wrong versions make more sense to me, I don't really understand the correct one : / Maybe I need a sleep or so,

Comment: I don't understand because I haven't defined the label "equal" anywhere and anyway I use it. I have defined "unequal" by writing "jne unequal". Why I don't need to write "jmp equal" anywhere? Or is it already defined as opposite when I write "jne unequal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get back to your first code:

```
         mov eax, a
         cmp eax, 4711
         jmp equal
equal:   add eax, 2
         jne unequal
unequal: sub eax, 2
```

Let's pretend the first instruction load `eax` with "a" (it actually would in TASM/MASM, but rather stick to explicit and accurate `[a]`, it's easier to read the source and works also in NASM).

Second instruction is `cmp`, which does subtract 4711 from eax, throws the result away (not storing it anywhere), and only flag register is affected. If "a" was 4711, then result of subtraction is zero, so ZF=1 then. Otherwise ZF=0. (for other flags affected by CMP see some documentation).

So on line 3 the `eax` still contains value from "a", and flag register contains result of `cmp eax,4711`. And you do `jmp`. This is unconditional jump, happening no matter what, so you directly continue to instruction at "equal" address, which is `add eax,2`. => You add 2 to "a" in every case.

Also the `add` itself affects flags, so for "a" == -2 the ZF=1, otherwise ZF=0!

Then comes the first conditional jump, branching the code, based on current flag register content. The `jne` is abbreviation of "jump not equal", and "equal" in this context means set zero flag (ZF=1).

So when "a" was -2, ZF is 1 ("is equal") ahead of `jne`, thus `jne` will NOT jump to the "unequal" address, but will continue to the next instruction (which is actually at "unequal" address anyway, so the `jne` is meaningless).

For "a" different from -2 the ZF will be 0 ("is not equal"), so `jne` will execute the jump on the provided label, continuing with instruction at address "unequal".

---

So you have to navigate the CPU away from instructions you don't want to execute.

```
    xor eax,eax   ; sets eax to 0, and ZF=1
    jz  label_1   ; ZF is 1, so jump is executed, CPU goes to "label_1"
    inc eax       ; this instruction is then skipped and not executed
label_1:
    ; eax being still 0, and ZF being still set ON
    ; whatever instruction is here, CPU will execute it after the "jz"
```

Slightly modified example to show the case when condition is false

```
    xor eax,eax   ; sets eax to 0, and CF=0, ZF=1, ...
    jc  label_1   ; CF is 0, so "jump carry" is NOT executed
    inc eax       ; this instruction is executed after "jc"
label_1:
    ; here eax is 1
    ; CF is still 0 (not affected by INC)
    ; but ZF is 0 (affected by INC)
```

Summary: you should have pretty good idea what instructions affect what flags, and in what way. When unsure, keep `CMP` + `Jcc` pair together (to not affect flag results from `cmp` accidentally). `Jcc` stands for any "conditional jump" instruction. When the condition is met, the jump to provided label is executed. Otherwise the `Jcc` instruction is ignored, and execution does continue with instruction right after it.

---

BTW, I personally would write that C code:

```
if (a == 4711) { a = a + 2 } else
               { a = a - 2 }
```

as:

```
    cmp [a],DWORD 4711
    mov eax,2
    je a_is_4711
    neg eax  ; -2 for non 4711 value
a_is_4711:
    add [a],eax
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer, I think I understood it now completely :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

In the first case, your `jne unequal` does nothing since control would go there anyway. You need to jump to *after* that.

In your second case, if the comparison is true, you both add and subtract 2, doing nothing.

You also don't store the result back where the original value was, you just leave it in `eax`.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit is correct except for one thing.

```
mov    eax, a
```

moves the address of "a" into eax, not the contents/value

---

This short snippet is done with NASM on Ubuntu 16.04 elf64

```
            section .text
    global _start
_start          
        mov     eax, a

        cmp     eax, 4711
        jnz     unequal
        add     eax, 2
        jmp     Done

    unequal:
        sub     eax, 2

Done:   mov [a], eax

        section .rodata         
a   dd  180308
```

It disassembles to;

```
00400080  B89C004000        mov eax,0x40009c

00400085  3D67120000        cmp eax,0x1267
0040008A  7505              jnz 0x400091
0040008C  83C002            add eax,byte +0x2
0040008F  EB03              jmp short 0x400094
00400091  83E802            sub eax,byte +0x2

00400094  8904259C004000    mov [0x40009c],eax
```

Variable "a" lives here

```
0040009C  54C00200
```

Note that @ 4000080 the address of a is moved into EAX, but @ Done (400091), whatever is in EAX is moved into that address. Notice too, the value @ "a" is stored in reverse order ([little endian](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html). Usually in code you'd see it as 0x2c054